# calculus of variations lemma

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $u,v \in C[0,1]$ such that
> $$
> \int_0^1 {u(x)\phi(x)+v(x)\phi'(x) dx} = 0 \text{ for all $\phi \in C_0^{\infty}[0,1]$}
> $$
> Show that $v$ is differentiable on the interval $(0,1)$ and that $u=v'$.

I am aware of the fundamental theorem of calculus of variations. How can this be applied here ?

Would appreciate any help

Comment: Do you mean $u = v'$?

Comment: @podiki Yes. There was a typo thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $A(x)=\int_0^x u(t)dt$ satisfies,
$\int A(x) \phi'(x)=-\int u(x) \phi(x)$ and thus the condition can be re-written as $\int (-A+v)\phi' = 0$ which implies that $v-A = \text{constant}.$ Thus we get differentiability from the fact that $A+\text{constant}\in C^1$ and thus $v'=u$.

Comment: Differentiability of $v$ is also to be proved.

Comment: @nls My problem was showing that v is differentiable. How to go from there would be clear to me

Comment: I will add that, give me a moment